# C# and OAuth2 refresh tokens

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, jwt

Does anyone have and examples or links to examples of making use of and generating refresh JWT tokens with C#. I can find lots of articles about theory but not many code examples.

Comment: maybe this: http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/

Comment: Awesome link! Thanks.